# React Native Navigation: Undefined is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I've recently ran into an issue with React Native Navigation that I cannot seem to solve.

I'm trying to organize my stacks by placing different stacks for different components in different files and then bringing them all together in the `router.js` file that I have created in `config/router.js`.

I keep getting this error
`undefined is not a function (near '...(0, _reactNativeNavigation.createStackManager)...')`

My `router.js` looks like this

```
import { createBottomTabNavigator } from 'react-navigation';
import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/Ionicons';

import { MapStack } from '../components/MapStack';


export const HomeViewTabs = createBottomTabNavigator({
    Map: {
        screen: MapStack,
        navigationOptions: {
            tabBarIcon:  ({tintColor}) => (
                <Icon name="ios-navigate" size={24} color={tintColor}/>
            )
        }},
    }, {
    initialRouteName: 'Map',
});
```

and my imported `MapStack.js`

```
import { createStackNavigator } from 'react-native-navigation';

import Map from '../screens/Map';
import BoxOverview from '../screens/BoxOverview';


export const MapStack = createStackNavigator({
    Map: { screen: Map },
    BoxOverview: { screen: BoxOverview},
});
```

My `index.js`

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { HomeViewTabs } from './config/router';


class App extends Component {
    render() {
        return <HomeViewTabs />;
    }
}

export default App;
```

Any help would be appreciated and any tips on my styling is also appreciated!

Edit:

Added photo of error for clarity

[image: Error]

File Structure

```
app/
+--components/
+----MapStack.js
+--config/
+----router.js
+--screens/
+----Box.js
+----BoxOverview.js
```

Solution:

I was importing the wrong React Navigation module in my `MapStack.js` file. It was supposed to be `import { createStackNavigation } from 'react-navigation'` and I had the module set as `'react-native-navigation'`...

Comment: In Which line of the code that you posted do you get the error?

Comment: The error is very vague and doesn't tell me what line the issue is on. I've added a picture for clarity

Comment: Could you post your .babelrc file? I'm experiencing the same issue, and I believe it might have something to do with the "add-module-exports" babel plugin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `MapStack.js` change this

```
import { createStackNavigator } from 'react-native-navigation';
```

To this

```
import { createStackNavigator } from 'react-navigation';
```

Found this solution after my friend pointed out that my imported module name was incorrect...

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're not importing the proper navigator in your router:

```
import { createStackNavigator } from 'react-navigation';
```

should be: `import { createBottomTabNavigator } from 'react-navigation';`

Comment: Can't believe I missed that but the issue is still pertaining even after adding the proper navigator.

Comment: @hpcsolo Is it still giving you the same error or is it flashing a different line error? Might be worth rebuilding it first and seeing if the error changes

Comment: I believe it has something to do with the `MapStack.js` component because I commented out `HomeViewTabs` and the issue is still there

Comment: it's the same exact error. Gonna try rebuilding it right now and let you know what happens!

Comment: @hpcsolo That's strange. Is your `MapStack.js` being wrapped in a HOC by any chance?

Comment: It's not being wrapped in an HOC as far as I'm aware

Comment: @hpcsolo Where are you importing the component and how is it being used? Are you using it with redux? The only reason I ask is because i came across a similar issue with a repo I maintain and the error was about how I was wrapping the component

Comment: I'm not using Redux. The `router.js` file is imported in `index.js` and I was using `HomeViewTabs` as the active component in the `render()` function. As for MapStacks, it's just a normal .js file that is holding some functionality and is imported into the `index.js`. Not sure If im clear enough, if not, just let me know! :)

Comment: Hmmm, @hpcsolo, what's your file structure & import look like? That might be the issue it's pointing on for `line 2` in your index file

Comment: Uploaded the file structure and the `index.js` in the main application

Comment: I don't see where your `index.js` file is in the file structure. Is it outside the `app` folder?

Comment: Found the solution to the problem, I posted it above. Thank you anyways!